# Webstorm console.log interrupts debugger

Tags: debugging, webstorm, console.log

I've a very simple node.js setup in webstorm. I can set a breakpoint on the res.send call and when I call localhost:8081 it breaks in as expected. Alas if I uncomment the console.log line just above the res.send method, it will break in the first time but that's the last time. I'll have to restart the application before the breakpoints will break again. Could the console.log be detaching the debugger? I can still see that the debug port is still live and the connection is still established between the node process and the java(webstorm) process?

Thanks,
Mark.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use('/', function (req, res) {
    // console.log('Hello');
    res.send('Hello Worlds');
})

app.listen(8081);

console.log('Server started on http://localhost:8081/');

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: can't recreate - to me, the breakpoint is hit every time the browser page is refreshed, with or without console.log...